# Why doesn't DrRacket recognize butlast?

Tags: list, racket

I was told butlast return all items in the list except the last item.
Here's a picture of my output when I try entering it manually:

[image]

The output was supposed to be '(1 2) because we removed the last item from the list.I found a documentation online on butlast but I'm not sure why the command isnt working for me: [https://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/cce/dracula.plt/6/0/planet-docs/manual/Lists.html#(def._((planet.*dracula..scm.*(cce._dracula..plt._6._0)._language)._butlast))](https://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/cce/dracula.plt/6/0/planet-docs/manual/Lists.html#(def._((planet._dracula..scm._(cce._dracula..plt._6._0)._language)._butlast)))

Comment: From the picture you haven't switched to the Dracula language. Is the intent to use the Dracula language or are you looking for similar features in the Racket language? DrRacket is a multiple language implementation and thus when using it with `#lang racket` you only get the features from that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you have referenced belongs to the [ACL2](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/acl2/) programming language, where [`butlast`](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/v7-4/combined-manual/index.html?topic=COMMON-LISP____BUTLAST) is a well defined built-in procedure.

Racket, however, does not have a built-in procedure named `butlast`. You can verify this using Racket's official documentation, which can be found at: https://docs.racket-lang.org/. This is why you are getting the error `butlast: undefined;` when applying the function, because the procedure is neither built-in nor one that you have defined.

In Racket, the built-in [`drop-right`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=drop-right#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop-right%29%29) procedure exists and works the same way as `butlast`. For example:

```
(drop-right '(1 2 3) 1)
=> '(1 2)
(drop-right '(1 2 3) 2)
=> '(1)
```

You can also manually create a `butlast` procedure as follows:

```
(define (butlast lst n)
  (let ([len (length lst)])
    (if (< len n)
        "handle error"
        (take lst (- len n)))))
```

For example:

```
(butlast '(1 2 3) 1)
=> '(1 2)
(butlast '(1 2 3) 2)
=> '(1)
```